# Is it possible to send ajax request from laravel event listener to controller?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, event-listener

Is it possible to send an AJAX response to a Laravel controller from an EventListener?

If for example a user registers and we have an event called SendEmailEvent which is being queued. Is it possible when the worker completes the task (it might be a second or several minutes after the registration is completed), to send an AJAX response to the controller with the listener and from there to add it to the view and display to the user a message like:

"Email was just sent. Please check your email." or maiby something like "The email you provided had a problem." or something like this without the need of refresh.

Is it possible to do this with AJAX without the refresh of the page by the user?

Comment: use job queues for mailing in listner

Comment: Study [broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/broadcasting) concept for that.